# Escaping single quote in string within Powershell before passing value to SQL

Tags: powershell, escaping, powershell-5.1, sqlps

I have a script that retrieves information relating to the files within a given folder path, and then passes those values via the SQLPS module and the SQL `INSERT INTO` command to populate my database table.

That works fine except for a few occasions where the file or folder path include an apostophe.

The relevant block of code is

```
$PathArowCount=0
$filelist = Get-ChildItem -Path $localPath -Recurse | Where-Object {!($_.PSIsContainer)} | Select DirectoryName, Name, Length, LastWriteTime 
ForEach ($file in $filelist)
{
    # Retrieve all values into variables. Value passed to the insert statement needs to be within single quotes, so escaping them out here so they're included later.
    $insFolder = "`'$($file.DirectoryName)`'"
    $insFile = "`'$($file.Name)`'"
    $insLength = "`'$($file.Length)`'"
    $insLastWrite = "`'$($file.LastWriteTime)`'"
    write-host "$insFolder`n$insFile`n$insLength`n$insLastWrite`n---"
    # Generate the SQL insert statement using the values above
    $sqlCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [$dbCompare].[dbo].[PathA] (FilePath,FileName,FileLength,LastWriteTime) VALUES ($insFolder,$insFile,$insLength,$insLastWrite)"
    # Execute the SQL command while also incrementing the row count for use later
    $PathArowCount = $PathArowCount + $sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
} 
write-output "$(Get-Date) - $PathArowCount rows (eg files found) inserted into table PathA"
```

Where as you can see I'm already setting the input values `$insFolder`, `$insFile`, `$insLength` and `$insLastWrite` that are passed to the SQL command to include single quotes since that's expected by SQL.

My problem is where a file/folder name includes an apostrophe/single quote, for instance :

c:\Myfiles\Keith's Document.docx

I get the following error from the `$sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` line :

```
Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): Incorrect syntax near 's'.
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string')'."
```

The `Write-Host` line shows me that at that point `$insFile` does correctly contain the entire string as expected with single quotes at either end, eg :

```
'Keith's Document.docx'
```

But from the error SQL is presumably seeing the value passed to it as

```
'Keith'
```

and then erroring by the unexpected argument :

```
s Document.docx'
```

I obviously need to find and Escape out that character where relevant, and I've tried various combinations for instance

```
$insFile = "`'$($file.Name).Replace("`'","\`'")`'"
```

where I'm escaping the single quotes within the comparison values with backticks, and trying to add a `\` to the backtick to escape that character when it reaches SQL, but every combination I've tried throws a Powershell error so I'm unsure what the magic combination is.

Comment: Use two single quotes instead of escaping : $insFile = 'c:\Myfiles\Keith''s Document.docx'
$insFile = $insFile.Replace("'","''")
$insFile

Comment: you should be using parameterized queries, this is not the right way to go

Comment: Thanks for the nudge in the right direction @SantiagoSquarzon I initially thought that was purely from a security perspective... but now having found how to do that and got that working I know better. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- **It is always preferable to use a [*parameterized query*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) rather than *string interpolation***, both to avoid quoting headaches and, more importantly, to eliminate any possibility of a [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack.

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68026479/45375) for an example based on [`SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery).
- If you do want to stick with string interpolation, you must escape value-internal `'` as `''`:

  ```bash
  $insFile = "'$($file.Name -replace "'", "''")'"

  # Alternative:
  $insFile = "'{0}'" -f ($file.Name -replace "'", "''")
  ```

---

##### Quoting considerations:

The **PowerShell** perspective with respect to *string literals*:

- Inside `"..."` - [expandable (interpolating) strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) - `'` chars. do *not* require escaping and can be used as-is.
- Inside `'...'` - [verbatim strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings) - embedded `'` chars., must be escaped as `''` - however, such strings are *not* involved here; see below.

The **T-SQL** perspective (where string literals are called [*character string constants*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql#character-string-constants)):

- `'...'` strings embedded in a query strings happen to *also* require escaping string-internal `'` as `''`.
- (`"..."` literals aren't supported by default, and neither form is interpolating)

Answer (score 1):

Big thanks to @SantiagoSquarzon for pointing me in what I didn't even realise was the right direction at the time. Got my script using parameterized queries (once I'd learnt how) thinking that would improve the security, and was pleasantly surprised to realise (with hindsight it's kind of obvious) that it also negates the issues with escape characters.

For anyone interested, the final working code I've ended up with is

```
$PathArowCount=0
$filelist = Get-ChildItem -Path $localPath -File -Recurse | Select DirectoryName, Name, Length, LastWriteTime 
ForEach ($file in $filelist)
{
    $sqlCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [$dbCompare].[dbo].[PathA] (FilePath,FileName,FileLength,LastWriteTime) VALUES (@Folder,@File,@Length,@LastWrite)"
    $sqlCommand.Parameters.Clear()
    $sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@folder", $($file.DirectoryName)) | Out-Null
    $sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@file", $($file.Name)) | Out-Null
    $sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@length", $($file.Length)) | Out-Null
    $sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@lastwrite", $($file.LastWriteTime)) | Out-Null
    $PathArowCount = $PathArowCount + $sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
} 
write-output "$PathArowCount rows (eg files found) inserted into table PathA"
```

*Note, from the comments below it appears the `.Add(` method as used here has been deprecated, so it might not work in newer versions. Confirmed to be working with Powershell 5.1 on Windows Server 2012 with SQL 2012, and Windows Server 2012 R2 with SQL 2016.*

Interestingly, before I reached that point and while still to wrangle the escape characters I found that while

```
$insFile = "`'$($file.Name).Replace("'","''")`'"
```

gives a Powershell error, splitting it into two lines like this

```
$insFileTmp = $($file.Name).Replace("'","''")
$insFile = "`'$insFileTmp`'"
```

worked fine and did what I was previously (before knowing better!) looking for.

Comment: you can also use a `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` as argument for your `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand` :) that way you dont need to hardcode the DB you are writing to in the query string

Comment: Cool. In this instance the entire script actually connects to two different databases on the same server, and it's the other one used in the initial connection string. Plus the uniquely named $dbcompare DB and PathA table are created by the script. So when reading my code it makes it a bit easier this way to keep track of what is being referenced where. :)

Comment: Good to see a parameterized solution, but I'm baffled by something like `$sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@file", $file.Name)` working, because the overloads of [SqlParameterCollection.Add()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add) don't seem to support such a two-argument call. Is `$sqlCommand` _not_ of type [`SqlCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand)?

Comment: Good to see a parameterized solution, but I'm baffled by something like `$sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@file", $file.Name)` working, because the overloads of [SqlParameterCollection.Add()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add) don't seem to support such a two-argument call. Is `$sqlCommand` _not_ of type [`SqlCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand)?

Comment: As for the escaping issue: note that, outside `"..."`,  you never need to enclose variable references in `$(...)` (and even inside `"..."` you only need it for _expressions_, not simple variable references). Thus, `$sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@file", $($file.Name))` can be simplified to `$sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@file", $file.Name)` for instance. Conversely, your string interpolation attempt was broken, because the `.Replace()` call must be _inside_ the embedded `$(...)`: `$insFile = "'$($file.Name.Replace("'","''"))'"` - also note that no backticks (`\``) are needed.

Comment: Yeah, I realise `$($..)` is often redundant, I've just gotten into the habit after being caught out enough times where it was needed, whereas doing it when not needed still works. Backticks were previously needed so what got to the SQL command still had single quotes around it... but it then became redundant once it was all parameterized.

Comment: @mklement0 Honestly have no idea regarding the parameters syntax... just googled for it and found a post (probably on here) with someone listing that syntax, so copied it and it worked. :) Weird to think after 10 years writing various things in Powershell, and 20 years of administering SQL (though to a lessor extent), this is the first time I've gotten the two talking to each other.

Comment: Thanks, @Keith. Curious re parameter syntax; the answer I link to from my answer uses a 3-parameter overload with subsequent setting of the `.Value` property. Obviously, the mysterious  2-parameter overload is more convenient, but relies on _inferring_ the parameter's data type, which may not always work as intended. Re `'`: as the correct form of the `$insFile = ...` in my previous comment shows, you do not to `\``-escape `'` inside `"..."`, ever (though doing so does no harm).

Comment: @mklement0 they probably meant `.AddWithValue` not `.Add` prob. a typo on the answer

Comment: @mklement0 I grabbed from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16734039/powershell-script-using-executenonquery-throws-exception-incorrect-syntax-nea and it worked, but having looked elsewhere now I see what you mean. Will probably tweak to use standard method rather than rely on luck with it inferring the data types. 
Remarks here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0 might explain, suggests syntax I used works but deprecated + I'm running script with PS5.1 on Server 2012, so might not work on newer.